# Cannot read property 'body' of undefined - TinyMCE in cakephp 2

Tags: javascript, tinymce

```
tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', true, "commentBox");

$('#commentBox').css("display:block");
tinymce.init({
    mode: "none",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink autosave link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
        "table contextmenu directionality emoticons template textcolor paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
    ],
    toolbar1: "newdocument fullpage | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | styleselect formatselect fontselect fontsizeselect",
    toolbar2: "cut copy paste | searchreplace | bullist numlist | outdent indent blockquote | undo redo | link unlink anchor image media code | insertdatetime preview | forecolor backcolor",
    toolbar3: "table | hr removeformat | subscript superscript | charmap emoticons | print fullscreen | ltr rtl | spellchecker | visualchars visualblocks nonbreaking template pagebreak restoredraft",
    menubar: false,
    toolbar_items_size: 'small',
    style_formats: [
        {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
        {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
        {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
        {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
        {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
        {title: 'Table styles'},
        {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
    ],
    templates: [
        {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},
        {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
    ]
});
tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, "commentBox");
closeModal();
```

I use this code but TinyMCE not working and in the console I see an error,

[image]

Tell me please why is the code not working and how will be right?

Comment: Hi Jeni, Firstly, welcome to Stack Overflow. I've inserted your TinyMCE configuration into a Fiddle (https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/Jrhaab) and can't see an issue. Also, I noticed the error is triggered by the save and getContent functions; are you seeing this issue when saving the content or immediately when the page is loaded?

Comment: Yes, I am set this TinyMCE in modal and I click any Id open the modal so I have set this code inside clicking on the function.

Code:
 function InquiryComment(InquiryId, InquiryAppId) {}

Comment: Code:
https://prnt.sc/uba54t

Comment: Is InquiryComment() meant to save the content or setup a new editor? Right now, it appears the AJAX call is completed, then you're removing an existing editor, and setting up a new editor? Is that the right intention?

Comment: Yes, This is needed.

Comment: You didn't quite answer my question, is InquiryComment() meant to save the content or setup a new editor?

Comment: There's a chance that TinyMCE isn't ready yet. Instead of using `tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, "commentBox");`, can you please try the `selector` property `tinymce.init`? More details available at https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#selector.

Comment: We just ran into the same error after a chrome update.
Turns out we were deleting the HTML under the tinymce editor - which might be happening when you close your modal.
Try adding `tinymce.remove("commentBox") ;` before you close the modal (or at least before it removes the modal content.